# cgi.FieldStorage() freezes when parsing empty POST data if enctype="multipart/form-data"

Tags: python

I use `http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` to implement a simple HTTP server.
I extract POST data with `cgi.FieldStorage`.

Here is my code, which is working fine except for one thing I will explain later :

```
import http.server;
import socketserver;
import cgi;

class GP(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler): 
    def do_POST(self):
        form = cgi.FieldStorage(fp=self.rfile, headers=self.headers, environ={'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST'}); # freeze dans certains cas
        print('OK');
        # here I can extract POST data
        self.send_response(200, 'OK');
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html');
        self.end_headers();
        self.wfile.write(bytes("thank you", "UTF-8"));

server = socketserver.ThreadingTCPServer(('', 80), GP);
server.serve_forever();
```

I have no access to the code which is making the request.
The enctype is `multipart/form-data` (because sometimes files are uploaded).

When the request does not contain any POST data, the line with `cgi.FieldStorage()` freezes (I think it tries to read nonexistent data).
As soon as there is at least one field in the POST data, it works.

Here is a sample HTTP form that can be used to create the faulty POST request :

```
<form method="post" action="http://the_ip/url" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

How can I modify my Python code to prevent `cgi.FieldStorage()` from freezing ?